# How to make a general input field class

Tags: html, css, bem

I am experimenting with BEM (CSS) and I am wondering how to make a class for styling all text fields background color and border (I am not using a CSS preprocessor yet).

For example, I have a text field inside my search field and also inside a contact form (and at 5 other places). Then I don't want to style the same background color and border in both cases, I want an `.input` class for all fields.

Can add the `.input` class on both elements like this:

```
<!-- Searchbox -->
<div class="searchbox">
   <input type="text" class="searchbox__field input">
   <button class="searchbox__button>Search!</button>
</div>

<!-- Contact form-->
<form class="contact-form">
   <div class="contact-form__control">
      <label class="contact-form__label">Name:</label>
      <input class="contact-form__field input">
   </div>
</form>

<!-- .input styling for all fields -->
<style>

   .input {
      border: 1px solid green;
      background-color: #dbdbdb;
      border-radius: 5px;
   }

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can add the `.input` class on both elements like this

Yes, you can:

```
<input type="text" class="searchbox__field input">
```

Here you have a *mix*: the same DOM node is both an element (`.searchbox__field`) and a block (`.input`).

See also: [the official documentation](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#mix).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your implementation of BEM is correct. I believe this is more "correct" for BEM naming convention, given your current HTML.

```css
/* searchbox block component */
.searchbox { /* css */ }

/* searchbox elements that depend upon the searchbox block */ 
.searchbox__field { /* css */ }
.searchbox__label { /* css */ }

/* Modifiers that change the style of the searchbox block */
.searchbox--green { /* css */ }
.searchbox--red { /* css */ }

/* contact-form-control block component */
.contact-form-control { /* css */ }

/* contact-form-control elements that depend upon the block */ 
.contact-form-control__field { /* css */ }
.contact-form-control__label { /* css */ }

/* Modifiers that change the style of the contact-form-control block */
.contact-form-control--green { /* css */ }
.contact-form-control--red { /* css */ }
```

I believe the purpose of the BEM naming convention is to break items up in to semi-logical, readable hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the "searchbox" class could be in a form instead of a div here. I'd look at "searchbox" and "contact-form" as two of the same blocks. Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding any of this too - I'm making a couple assumptions of the overall structure.

Would this be a better solution?

```
<!-- Searchbox -->
<form class="form">
   <input type="text" class="form__input">
   <button class="form__button">Search!</button>
</form>

<!-- Contact form-->
<form class="form">
   <div class="form__control">
      <label class="form__label">Name:</label>
      <input class="form__input">
   </div>
</form>

<!-- .input styling for all fields -->
<style>
   .form__input {
      border: 1px solid green;
      background-color: #dbdbdb;
      border-radius: 5px;
   }
</style>
```

Then if one input field was going to vary you could add a modifier.

Search field input could be used just for example sake:

```
<form class="form">
   <input type="text" class="form__input form--open">
   <button class="form__button">Search!</button>
</form>
```